# HtmlAgility parsing ajax responce

Tags: c#, regex, html-agility-pack

I have the following result, taken from Fiddler, during Ajax Post request, which I need to parse in order to get image links. Is it possible to do with HtmlAgility, or should I go for Regex?

```
"\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv class=\"media-window\" style=\"position: fixed; left: 25px; top: 25px; right: 25px;\r\n    display: none; bottom: 10px;\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cspan class=\"layer-close\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"close\"\u003eClose\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"stop\"\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"thumbs-wrapper\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"media-thumbs\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"media-pager previous-set\"\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003e&lt;&lt; Previous\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cul class=\"thumb\"\u003e\r\n                \r\n                \u003cli\u003e\r\n                    \r\n                    \u003ca href=\"javascript:void(0);\" rel=\"http://website/image1.jpg\"\u003e\r\n                        \u003cimg src=\"ttp://website/image1.jpg\" alt=\"0\" /\u003e\r\n                    \u003c/a\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\r\n                \r\n                \u003cli\u003e\r\n                    \r\n                    \u003ca href=\"javascript:void(0);\" rel=\"ttp://website/image1.jpg\"\u003e\r\n                        \u003cimg src=\"ttp://website/image1.jpg\" alt=\"1\" /\u003e\r\n                    \u003c/a\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\r\n                \r\n            \u003c/ul\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"media-pager next-set\"\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003eNext &gt;&gt;\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"stop\"\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"main-image\"\r\n        style=\"overflow: hidden; position: relative;\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cul\u003e\r\n            \u003cli class=\"media-pager previous-img\"\u003e\u003cspan\u003e&lt;&lt; Previous photo\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\r\n            \u003cli class=\"media-pager next-img\"\u003e\u003cspan\u003eNext photo &gt;&gt;\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\r\n        \u003c/ul\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"image-wrapper zoom\"\r\n            style=\"position:relative;display:inline-block;\"\r\n            \u003e\r\n            \r\n            \r\n            \u003cscript type=\"text/javascript\"\u003e\r\n                $(document).ready(function () {\r\n                    $(\"ul.thumb li\").each(function () {\r\n                        if ($(this).children(\"a\").children(\"img\").attr(\"alt\") == \u00270\u0027) {\r\n"
```

Comment: Why dont you try that pack?

Comment: Hi I did that but since this is not well structured, or at least I need somehow to decode the string, so it will become structured hmtl code. I am not getting the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
string str = "\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv class=\"media-window\" style=\"position: fixed; left: 25px; top: 25px; right: 25px;\r\n    display: none; bottom: 10px;\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cspan class=\"layer-close\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"close\"\u003eClose\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"stop\"\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"thumbs-wrapper\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"media-thumbs\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"media-pager previous-set\"\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003e&lt;&lt; Previous\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cul class=\"thumb\"\u003e\r\n                \r\n                \u003cli\u003e\r\n                    \r\n                    \u003ca href=\"javascript:void(0);\" rel=\"http://website/image1.jpg\"\u003e\r\n                        \u003cimg src=\"ttp://website/image1.jpg\" alt=\"0\" /\u003e\r\n                    \u003c/a\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\r\n                \r\n                \u003cli\u003e\r\n                    \r\n                    \u003ca href=\"javascript:void(0);\" rel=\"ttp://website/image1.jpg\"\u003e\r\n                        \u003cimg src=\"ttp://website/image1.jpg\" alt=\"1\" /\u003e\r\n                    \u003c/a\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\r\n                \r\n            \u003c/ul\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"media-pager next-set\"\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003eNext &gt;&gt;\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"stop\"\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"main-image\"\r\n        style=\"overflow: hidden; position: relative;\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cul\u003e\r\n            \u003cli class=\"media-pager previous-img\"\u003e\u003cspan\u003e&lt;&lt; Previous photo\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\r\n            \u003cli class=\"media-pager next-img\"\u003e\u003cspan\u003eNext photo &gt;&gt;\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\r\n        \u003c/ul\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"image-wrapper zoom\"\r\n            style=\"position:relative;display:inline-block;\"\r\n            \u003e\r\n            \r\n            \r\n            \u003cscript type=\"text/javascript\"\u003e\r\n                $(document).ready(function () {\r\n                    $(\"ul.thumb li\").each(function () {\r\n                        if ($(this).children(\"a\").children(\"img\").attr(\"alt\") == \u00270\u0027) {\r\n";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(str);
foreach (var selectNode in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(selectNode.Attributes["src"].Value);
}
```

UPDATE:
The code I've tried to parse images from google.com:

```
var url = "http://google.com";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());

foreach (var selectNode in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]"))
{
      Console.WriteLine(selectNode.Attributes["src"].Value);
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but still not working .. I am using the following code: HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(Url, data, ct);
doc.Load(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
try
{
 foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]"))
 {
  string r = link.Attributes["src"].Value;
 }
}

Comment: Are you sure you get right message from your post? I just tried it with get to google.com - it works perfectly, so I think the problem not in the html parsing.

Comment: I have compared the Fidler result with response result ... it is the same... next I tried to parse with //img[@src] or even //img just to get some result ... without any success till now

Comment: What if you try to save result in the string variable, then parse it?

Comment: I am not sure what is happening but... if I put the above code in string kp and load in doc.LoadHtml(kp); I get formated html code.... However the result from doc.Load(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()); is not formated

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple :

```
var decodedString = Regex.Unescape(yourString);
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is working:

```
var decodedString = Regex.Unescape(yourString);
```

Comment: Add some explanation how this answer help OP to fix current issue and as well others with same issue.Thanks